# Connect to Outlook COM with Outlook 2016 Microsoft Store

Tags: c++, outlook, outlook-addin, windows-dev-center

I'm using the standard COM API of Outlook. It works perfectly well. 
But since the release of Outlook 2016 in the Microsoft Store version, the COM is not accessible anymore.

Do you know any way to access it ?

Comment: Is it possible, You are not authenticate. You should use OAuth1 to authenticate to get Access token, then you can call  API. You could refer to this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started

Comment: Sorry I was not talking about Outlook.com but the ActiveX COM object of Outlook

Comment: Is it possible that version numbers of the object libraries don’t exactly correspond to the version numbers of the applications. You could refer to this link: https://office-watch.com/2018/access-persistence-reference-problems/

Comment: this refers to standalone version of Outlook and not the bundled Microsoft Store version

Comment: Have you checked this url? https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/310803/how-to-resolve-reference-issues-in-an-access-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Both things were happening, I was using a IUnknown instead of IDispatch, CoExInitialize was badly called, and my COM registration was messed up.